# How to fix "ELIFECYCLE" error, during the initial React native setup

Tags: react-native

Am following the React Native beginner course on udemy, and when following the setting up process, everything works and the builder opens for a few second, then it blackout and I see the Following ERR message

[PowerShell Err massege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuJND.png)

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\ALi_O\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Users\ALi_O\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\React Native\3.1 rn-starter.zip\rn-starter\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\ALi_O\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ALi_O\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: E:\React Native\3.1 rn-starter.zip\rn-starter
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ALi_O\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ALi_O\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd E:\React Native\3.1 rn-starter.zip\rn-starter
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ALi_O\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but i think you should try to use another node version. I had a friend who worked on a windows machine and expo project and there he had to downgrade Node to v10.x and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the latest node.js has problems to work on Windows and the only fix for me was downgrading to Node.js 10.x.

I am running on 10.16.3 and it works all fine:

```
npm install -g node@10.16.3
```